# How to convert a loop into vector assignment notation

Tags: loops, fortran, vectorization

How would one go about converting a loop like this:

```
Do i = 2,101
   a(i) = b(i)
   c(i-1) = d(i) + d(i-1)
   d(i) = e(i) + 12
Enddo
```

in the vector notation of `Fortran` ? We can obviously split the loops, and do something like

```
a(2:101) = b(2:101)
```

but the last 2 statements depend on each other so that won't really work.

Comment: What do you mean by vectorization? SIMD instructions or just rewriting in an array assignment notation?

Comment: I should have specified - just rewriting it, no SIMD stuff

Comment: Ok, but in Fortran vectorization normally means SIMD.

Comment: Note `c` does not depend on `e` *at all*.  ( Both of the present answers are wrong.. )

Comment: @agentp - I think the Nth value of c depends on the N+1st value of `d`, and the Nth value of `e`. See my new answer.

Comment: Don't convert please ! The loop is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jeff Irwin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29657930/120261) has the right idea by writing out a few iterations of the loop. `c` and `d` are updated as:

```
c(1) = d(2) + d(1)
d(2) = e(2) + 12

c(2) = d(3) + d(2) = d(3) + e(2) + 12
d(3) = e(3) + 12

c(3) = d(4) + d(3) = d(4) + e(3) + 12
d(4) = e(4) + 12
```

So, the Nth value of `c` depends on the `N+1st` value of `d`, and the `Nth` value of `e`. We can write the whole loop as:

```
a(2:101) = b(2:101)
c(1) = d(2) + d(1)
c(2:100) = d(3:101) + e(2:100) + 12
d(2:101) = e(2:101) + 12
```

Comment: I also think this is the correct way to do it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

**OLD**

```
Do i = 2,101
   a(i) = b(i)
   c(i-1) = d(i) + d(i-1)
   d(i) = e(i) + 12
Enddo
```

**NEW**

```
a(2:101) = b(2:101)
c(1:100) = d(2:101) + d(1:100)
d(2:101) = e(2:101) + 12
```

If this is any faster, I doubt it, and it may be more obscure as far as design intent is so vectorizing may not always be the best way to go.

**EDIT 1**

```
a(2:101) = b(2:101)
d(2:101) = e(2:101) + 12
c(1:100) = d(2:101) + d(1:100)
```

Since `d` depends on `e` only and `c` depends on `d`. From the loop above `d(1)` needs to have been defined earlier.

Comment: My bad. I fixed it. Tx

Comment: +1 i'd argue in this case the original was not so good for readability since quite a few folks had trouble figuring it out!

Comment: I understand `d(i)+d(i-1)` a lot better than `d(2:101)+d(1:100)`

Comment: This is wrong - c(i-1) depends on the d(i) computed in the previous iterations. The way you have written these will not honour that dependence. @mtrw 's answer is the correct one - check out how he unrolls the loop.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, take a closer look at your un-vectorized loop.  The first few iterations will look like this:

```
a(2) = b(2)
c(1) = d(2) + d(1)
d(2) = e(2) + 12

a(3) = b(3)
c(2) = d(3) + d(2)
d(3) = e(3) + 12

a(4) = b(4)
c(3) = d(4) + d(3)
d(4) = e(4) + 12
```

Unless `d` has been initialized earlier in the code, this could lead to unpredictable behavior (specifically, `d(2)` is used to calculate `c(1)` before `d(2)` itself is assigned).

---

*EDIT:  The rest of this post is incorrect, as pointed out by High Performance Mark.  I'm leaving it here anyways for reference.*

Note that `c` depends on `d`, but `d` does not depend on `c`.  Thus, you could rewrite your code as follows:

```
a(2: 101) = b(2: 101)
d(2: 101) = e(2: 101) + 12
c(1: 100) = d(2: 101) + d(1: 100)
```

This is very similar to mtrw's answer, but note the `+` instead of `-` and the indices of `c` in the last line.

Comment: But this is wrong, it flips the ordering of the updates to `d` and `c`.  Since the update to `c` depends on the values in `d` this is a significant change.